# No module named <module>

Tags: python, import

I'm really new to Python - I'm trying to do this:

```
import bottle.run, bottle.route, bottle.template

@bottle.Bottle.route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

and here is the listing of my current working directory, with my script being `bot.py`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ctote gos-eng    196 Oct  1 20:54 bot.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 ctote gos-eng 148901 Oct  1 19:55 bottle.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 ctote gos-eng 167884 Oct  1 20:26 bottle.pyc
-r-xr-xr-x 1 ctote gos-eng      0 Oct  1 20:25 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 ctote gos-eng   4096 Oct  1 19:55 pip-egg-info
-rw-r--r-- 1 ctote gos-eng   1692 Oct  1 19:55 PKG-INFO
-rw-r--r-- 1 ctote gos-eng   1057 Oct  1 19:55 README.rst
-rw-r--r-- 1 ctote gos-eng   1516 Oct  1 19:55 setup.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 ctote gos-eng   4096 Oct  1 19:55 test
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
python bot.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bottle.run, bottle.route, bottle.template ImportError: No module named run
```

Within `bottle.py`, there's this:

```
def run(self, **kwargs):
        ''' Calls :func:`run` with the same parameters. '''
        run(self, **kwargs)
```

What am I doing wrong? Ideally I'd rather not have my script in this directory, but I figured this was the easiest way to get started..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bottle` is a module. `bottle.run` is an *object* (a function), contained in that module.

Import just the module:

```
import bottle
```

and refer to `bottle.run` in your code, or import the objects from the module:

```
from bottle import run, route, template
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is exactly what I needed to do. At what point is the __init__.py file actually needed?

Comment: @MrDuk: that's only needed in a package. `bottle` is not a package, and neither is your project.